# Why did Arjuna fight with the Gandharvas frequently when Chitrasena gave him divine weapons and taught him how to dance?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, gandharva

Chitrasena taught Aruna how to dance which was important in his last year of exile. The Gandharvas gave him divine weapons so why did he fight them?